# Vector inequality contrains for minimize function in mathematica

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica, minimize

I'm minimizing a function in Mathematica related to a variable length vector:
`x = Table[Subscript[X, i], {i, n}]`

My minimize function is currently:
`Minimize[{x.\[CapitalSigma].x, \[Mu].x >= R && Total[x] == 1 && 
   Subscript[X, 1] >= 0 && Subscript[X, 2] >= 0 && 
   Subscript[X, 3] >= 0 && Subscript[X, 4] >= 0}, x]`

How can I code the non-negativity constraints so that all elements of x are non-negative regardless of the length of the vector?

Answer (score 5):

```
       { ... , And@@Table[Subscript[X,i]>=0 , {i,n} ] } ...
```